# How to replace multiple substrings in a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to replace multiple substrings from a string (max length 32 of input string). I have a big dictionary which can have millions of items as a key-value pair. I need to check for each word if this word is present in the dictionary and replace with the respective value if present in the dictionary. The input string can have multiple trailing spaces.

This method is being called millions of time, due to this, it's affecting the performance badly.

Is there any scope of optimization in the code or some other better way to do this.

```
public static string RandomValueCompositeField(object objInput, Dictionary<string, string> g_rawValueRandomValueMapping) {

if (objInput == null)
    return null;

string input = objInput.ToString();
if (input == "")
    return input;

//List<string> ls = new List<string>();
int count = WhiteSpaceAtEnd(input);
foreach (string data in input.Substring(0, input.Length - count).Split(' ')) {

    try {
        string value;
        gs_dictRawValueRandomValueMapping.TryGetValue(data, out value);
        if (value != null) {

            //ls.Add(value.TrimEnd());
            input = input.Replace(data, value);
        }
        else {
            //ls.Add(data);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }

}

//if (count > 0)
//    input = input + new string(' ', count);
    //ls.Add(new string(' ', count));

return input;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I missed one important thing in the question. substring can occur only once inthe input string. Dictionay key and value have same number of characters.

Comment: "max length 32" is this a max length of input string or max length of words to replace? In any case consider to use StringBuilder, because strings are immutable and each call to `Replace` will create a new string. BTW in your current code example you do not use that new string, so `input.Replace(data, value);` just wasting CPU time and create memory traffic

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and faster if you kept your dictionary in a database (say SQLite - in memory if you will), and create a simple words table, doing an EXISTS search?

Comment: Maybe you should post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Possibly avoiding something like this:  `input.Replace(data, value);` (which isn't doing anything). It could also be interesting to know whether LINQ's deferred execution/caching is an option in your scenario. It also looks like you're not exactly using the last version of the language. So, possibly, neither the Framework's.

Comment: sorry I missed `input = input.Replace(data, value);`..Edited the code

Comment: If you need to get rid of whitespace you can use `Trim`, `TrimEnd`, and `TrimStart`.

Comment: One thing you can do is a `Distinct` after the `Split` so you don't end up running `Replace` on the same word multiple times.

Comment: @juharr .. I don't want to get rid of whitespace.

Comment: You're doing a `Substring` to skip the white space at the end before the split.  That could just be `input.TrimEnd().Split()` instead.

Comment: @juharr I think substring will be faster than TrimEnd, because TrimEnd will return a new string.

Comment: @viveknuna So does `Substring`.

Comment: Like @AleksAndreev mentioned try creating a `StringBuilder` from your `input` and doing `Replace` on that instead.  Also the `TrimEnd` isn't about performance it's about not having to recreate code that already exists.

Comment: @juharr I think Replace method can be extended, which will replace from index till the length of substring.. because substring can occur only once in the input string. But I am not able to implement it.

Comment: call to Replace could replacing something at any position in the string. E.g.`"crown crow horse".Replace("crow", "jay") == "jayn jay horse"`

Comment: Method argument is `g_rawValueRandomValueMapping` and in the loop `gs_dictRawValueRandomValueMapping`. Is this a typo or different dictionaries?

Comment: @bahrom gs_dictRawValueRandomValueMapping is class member. You can ignore the parameter g_dictRawValueRandomValueMapping. I was passing as parameter initially. Then I made this parameter class member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will take an input string and will build a new string by finding "words" (any consecutive non-whitespace) and then checking if that word is in a dictionary and replacing it with the corresponding value if found.  This will fix the issues of `Replace` doing replacements on "sub-words" (if you have "hello hell" and you want to replace "hell" with "heaven" and you don't want it to give you "heaveno heaven").  It also fixes the issue of swapping.  For example if you want to replace "yes" with "no" and "no" with "yes" in "yes no" you don't want it to first turn that into "no no" and then into "yes yes".

```
public string ReplaceWords(string input, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    int wordStart = -1;
    int wordLength = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // If the current character is white space check if we have a word to replace
        if(char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i]))
        {
            // If wordStart is not -1 then we have hit the end of a word
            if(wordStart >= 0)
            {
                // get the word and look it up in the dictionary
                // if found use the replacement, if not keep the word.
                var word = input.Substring(wordStart, wordLength);
                if(replacements.TryGetValue(word, out var replace))
                {
                    builder.Append(replace);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(word);
                }
            }

            // Make sure to reset the start and length
            wordStart = -1;
            wordLength = 0;

            // append whatever whitespace was found.
            builder.Append(input[i]);
        }
        // If this isn't whitespace we set wordStart if it isn't already set
        // and just increment the length.
        else
        {
            if(wordStart == -1) wordStart = i;
            wordLength++;
        }
    }

    // If wordStart is not -1 then we have a trailing word we need to check.
    if(wordStart >= 0)
    {
        var word = input.Substring(wordStart, wordLength);
        if(replacements.TryGetValue(word, out var replace))
        {
            builder.Append(replace);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append(word);
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```